# Found a kitten in the street, is it dangerous to keep him in the same environment with my 2 year old cat?

Tags: cats, strays

As I was coming back from the gym with my wife wound a kitten in the street crying, dirty and hungry. We could simply not let him there. We got him home. Is it dangerous to keep him in the same environment with my 2 year old cat?

I called a vet and he said "don't let your cat go to close to him". Thing is the kitten is full of bugs and at this time (night) I cannot find anything to help him out.

We cleaned him as much as we could (with some soap) and put him in a cat box near a heater so he can stay cozy.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment for a full answer, but for a short answer, take your vet's advice. The kitten may be carrying parasites or communicable diseases that can be a danger to your cat. Make sure to keep it somewhere where they can have no contact with each other, and wash your hands (and anything else) thoroughly after handling the kitten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the short term, yes, both cats are in danger.

The kitten is small and relatively defenseless, and your adult cat will not appreciate a new predator in its territory, even a small one that poses no direct threat. The adult may need a week or two to accept the new smell as a “normal” part of his/her territory.

The kitten may also be carrying diseases and/or parasites; it should be checked out by a vet (and given all appropriate shots) before allowing it any contact with other animals. It is also probably scared out of its mind right now, so the best thing you can do is give it a warm and cozy place that will let it learn it is safe while it gets used to the new smells and sounds of your home.

You will know when it’s okay to let the cats meet when they seem more curious about each other than scared/angry.

Comment: I took the small one to the vet and indeed I tried to follow what you said (and the vet said). It was impossible to separate them most of the time. The bigger one was anxious in the beginning and then tried to attack the small one a few times (always sneaking from behind). I got afraid so I took the small one to my parents. The small one is extremely friendly and I will have him back over the weekend, but I am afraid the big one will still be anxious.

Comment: There are good guides on how to introduce two cats together. In short, first swap their blankets (and smells), then allow them to actually smell each other, but not see each other. Thirdly, let them see but not touch each other. Then allow supervised interaction. Only go forward a step when they seem like they are accepting each other.